# Which one is more effective or better practice, cleanup function with abort controller or changing local variable to false in React component unmount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very confused to chose the better one,  can you suggest which one is better choice and why ?

App.js

with abortcontroller

```
  useEffect(() => {
  const abortCtrl = new AbortController();
  const opts = { signal: abortCtrl.signal };

  fetch(URL, opts)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => setTodo(data))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

  return () => abortCtrl.abort();
}, []);
```

with local variable

```
  useEffect(() => {
  let isActive = true;

  fetch(URL)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      if (isActive) {
        setTodo(data);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

  return () => {
    isActive = false;
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: What things do you want to achieve here? Why need to create an local variable or use`AbortController`?

Comment: To cancel fetch request or not making changes to component which is unmounted from DOM

Comment: This [article](https://dev.to/pallymore/clean-up-async-requests-in-useeffect-hooks-90h) might help. Solution 1 is better when you have very slow request and you don't need the result anymore.